# How to set thickness of scrollbars in scrollviewer

Tags: xaml, datagrid, scrollbar, winui-3

How can I control the thickness of a horizontal or vertical `Scrollbar` that gets displayed in a / as part of a `DataGrid` control?
I would like them to be displayed "thicker" than how that are displayed at the moment.

*Remark: For the sake of showing an example application with dummy data in a `DataGrid` the screenshots below are based on the "Xaml brewer" sample application which you can find [here](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2021/09/28/using-the-windows-community-toolkit-datagrid-with-winui-3-and-entity-framework-core/).*

I have a `DataGrid` that always shows vertical and horizontal scrollbars (I removed all non-essential XAML code):

```
<Page
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>

        <controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </controls:DataGrid>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

This is how the scrollbars are displayed normally, i.e. the DataGrid has focus, but the mouse is *not* currently hovering over one of the scrollbars. They are displayed very thin, so that the users of my application sometimes do not recognize them:

[image]

This is how a `Scrollbar` is displayed when the mouse *is* currently hovering over one of them (in this case the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom). Now this one is displayed a bit thicker and thus easier to see:

[image]

Is there are way to display the scrollbars thicker / set their thickness, or specify that they should always be displayed in the way they are displayed when hovering over them (see second screenshot above, they are displayed thicker in that case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there are way to display the scrollbars thicker / set their thickness

You might be able to re-style the `ScrollBar` but an empty `ScrollBar` style should give you a WPF-like `ScrollBar`.

```xml
<controls:DataGrid>
    <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

> specify that they should always be displayed in the way they are displayed when hovering over them

I have published a NuGet package called [AK.Toolkit.WinUI3.ScrollBarExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AK.Toolkit.WinUI3.ScrollBarExtensions) for this. Try it out and see if it fits your requirements.

```xml
<Page
    :
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="using:AK.Toolkit.WinUI3" />

    <controls:DataGrid
        toolkit:ScrollBarExtensions.KeepHorizontalExpanded="True"
        toolkit:ScrollBarExtensions.KeepVerticalExpanded="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />

</Page>
```

- [GitHub](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit#:%7E:text=ScrollBarExtensions.KeepExpanded)
- [YouTube](https://youtu.be/8m82fXl0LKk)

Comment: I tested your nuget package and it works very well thank you. The scrollbars stay in "expanded" mode when setting the "KeepExpanded" properties you provided in your example. Thank you :)

Comment: I tested the "KeepExpanded" properties a bit more. It seems that they are applied correctly the first time the UI loads, but then later it falls back to the standard "non-expanded" mode.

Comment: Weird. Can't reproduce it in the sample app. Do you mean if you leave it for a while the ``ScrollBar`` hides? I would really appreciate it if you could post an issue in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit/issues).

Comment: I am not entirely sure. What I can tell you is that I have a "Page" that uses NavigationCacheMode.Required in order to keep its data. When I see the page for the first time the scrollviewers are expanded correctly. But when I go to another page and then re-navigate to the first page, the scrollviewers are no longer expanded.

Ok, I will post an issue in the GitHub repo.

Comment: I have posted the issue in the github repo: https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit/issues/44

Comment: This is fixed in AK.Toolkit.ScrollBarExtensions v1.0.5. Thanks for the feedback @Martin!